# Can I generate presigned link before I put the item into S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Lambda to receive and process an image, store the image into S3 bucket, and generate a presigned link to make the processed image accessible. However, for Lambda to process image and store in into S3, it takes time, which cause the response quite slow.

Is it possible to first generate a presigned link and send it to the client, in the meanwhile do the image processing and save to S3? When the client's request arrives at S3, the processing and saving should have been down.

Comment: You should consider an eventually consistent or asynchronous pattern

Comment: I don't think async is the solution here. Base on my limited knowledge, I need to store the img into S3 and then based on its key to generate the presigned link. I wonder if it is possible to generate a link first so I can instantly respond to the request, and then save the img to S3.

Comment: Yes.  The presigned link basically gives you permission to download an object.  No part of the signing validates the objects exists.  Most clients, however, won't be happy getting an object that errors out because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: If you're planning on uploading the original image to your Lambda function then be aware that both API Gateway (if you're using it) and Lambda functions have payload limits (10MB and 6MB respectively).